# Hodge decomposition in elliptic complexes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, smooth-manifolds, elliptic-pde, differential-operators

**EDIT:** In the book "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris the authors prove the Hodge decomposition for the Dolbeault operator $\bar\partial$ on differential forms on a compact complex manifold (see Ch. 0). Then they mention without proof (see p. 89) that similar decomposition holds for the de Rham operator $d$ on forms on any compact Riemannian manifold, and the proof is similar (they actually use this fact on p. 116).

I am teaching a course following mostly this book. I prefer to prove both cases of the Hodge decomposition. **I am wondering if there is a unified approach of doing that**.

For example  de Rham and Dolbeault complexes are examples of [elliptic complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_complex) of differential operators between vector bundles.

**Is there a Hodge decomposition theorem for elliptic complexes on a compact manifold in the class of infinitely smooth sections?**

A reference would be very helpful, especially if it is of introductory level, i.e. appropriate for the course.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is a Hodge decomposition for elliptic complexes on compact *oriented* Riemannian manifolds.

**$L^2$-version**. Let $(M,g)$ be a compact oriented Riemannian manifold and let
$$
0 \to \Gamma(E_0) \to \Gamma(E_1) \to \dots \to \Gamma(E_m) \to 0
$$
be an elliptic differential complex with the arrows given by the differential operators $D_0,\dotsc,D_{m-1}$, where each $E_i$ is equipped with a metric and a compatible connection. Thus we have formal adjoints and can form the Laplacians:
$$
\Delta_i := D_i^* \circ D_i + D_{i-1} \circ D_{i-1}^*: \Gamma(E_i) \to \Gamma(E_i).
$$
Then we get the Hodge decomposition
$$
L^2(E_i) = \ker(\Delta_i) \oplus \operatorname{ran}(D_{i-1}) \oplus \operatorname{ran}(D_i^*).
$$

I learnt this from our own Liviu Nicolaescu's *[Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812770295)*. More precisely, this is Chapter 10.4.3 in the notes (my version is from 9. Sep 2018).

**EDIT:** As per OP's comment, I am adding the smooth version I know of.

**$C^{\infty}$-version**. Consider the total vector bundle $E := \bigoplus_{i=0}^{m} E_i$ and the Laplacian $\Delta = D \circ D^* + D^* \circ D$, i.e. $\Delta$ is just a tuple of Laplacians $\Delta_i: \Gamma(E_i) \to \Gamma(E_i)$. The following statements are equivalent:

(1) $\Delta$ is Fredholm and $\Gamma(E) = \ker(\Delta) + \operatorname{ran}(\Delta)$ (note, this is just a sum, not a direct sum);

(2) The complex itself is Fredholm and satisfies the Hodge decomposition:
$$
\Gamma(E) = \ker(\Delta) \oplus \operatorname{ran}(D) \oplus \operatorname{ran}(D^*)
$$
This can be found in Chapter 1 of [van den Ban and Crainic's lectures on *Analysis on Manifolds*](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Eban00101/geoman2017/AS-2017rev.pdf), more precisely exercise 1.3.15, if you don't mind following the exercises and working it out from the preceding theory, but I don't know a more self-contained source.

Comment: @LSpice: The notes are also freely available, the last version is here: https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer to have Hodge decomposition for infinitely smooth sections rather than $L^2$. (Another less important remark is that in the mentioned lecture notes the differential operators have the first order.)

Comment: @asv: I believe I have seen the Hodge decomposition stated for $\Gamma(E)$, where $E$ is the total vector bundle. Would that work for you? In fact, I think I even remember where.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442705/is-there-a-unified-way-to-prove-hodge-decomposition-in-de-rham-and-dolbeault-coh#comment1142606_442710), if you prefer the link to the free version (I know some people don't like having links to paywalled content in their posts), then please feel free to overwrite my edit.  I just like to have some link when possible.

Comment: @LSpice: I think, that's fine. That way we have both links.

Comment: In seems that in the second reference you mentioned Exercise 1.3.15 is not about a proof of the Hodge decomposition, but just an equivalent reformation of it.

Comment: @asv: well, it is, but you can ignore the inverse direction, if you are not interested in it. Though I find an equivalence to be a stronger statement and I haven't found anywhere else *necessary and sufficient conditions* for a Hodge decomposition to hold.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I think that Chapter 1 is that book does not develop enough tools to prove Hodge decomposition. Exercise 1.3.15 might be potentially helpful to prove it as it might contain some intermediate steps, but that's all as far I understand. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @asv: Ah, I see now what you meant. Indeed one has to get the ingredients to establish (1) for concrete cases from elsewhere, so it's not self-contained in that regard. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.